# Jest: Mock a _HOC_ or _curried_ function

Tags: javascript, jestjs

Given the following function:

**./http.js**

```
const http = {
  refetch() {
    return (component) => component;
  }
}
```

I would like to mock the function in a test as follows:

**./__tests__/someTest.js**

```
import { refetch } from './http';

jest.mock('./http', () => {
  return {
    refetch: jest.fn();
  }
}

refetch.mockImplementation((component) => {
  // doing some stuff
})
```

But I'm receiving the error

```
TypeError: _http.refetch.mockImplementation is not a function
```

How can I mock the refetch function in the given example?

---

**update:**

When I modify the mock function slightly to:

```
jest.mock(
  '../http',
  () => ({ refetch: jest.fn() }),
);
```

I get a different error:

```
TypeError: (0 , _http.refetch)(...) is not a function
```

My guess it's something with the syntax where the curried function (or HOC function) is not mapped properly. But I don't know how to solve it.

---

Some of the real code I'm trying to test.

*Note: The example is a bit sloppy. It works in the application. The example given is to give an idea of the workings.*

**./SettingsContainer**

```
// ...some code

  return (
    <FormComponent
      settingsFetch={settingsFetch}
      settingsPutResponse={settingsPutResponse}
    />
  );
}

const ConnectedSettingsContainer = refetch(
  ({
    match: { params: { someId } },
  }) => ({
    settingsFetch: {
      url: 'https://some-url.com/api/v1/f',
    },
    settingsPut: (data) => ({
      settingsPutResponse: {
        url: 'https://some-url.com/api/v1/p',
      }
    }),
  }),
)(SettingsContainer);

export default ConnectedSettingsContainer;
```

Then in my component I am getting the settingsPutResponse via the props which [react-refetch](https://github.com/heroku/react-refetch) does.

I want to test if the user can re-submit a form after the server has responded once or twice with a 500 until a 204 is given back.

**./FormComponent**

```
// ...code
const FormComp = ({ settingsResponse }) => {
  const [success, setSuccess] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (settingsResponse && settingsResponse.fulfilled) {
      setSuccess(true);
    }
  }, [settingsResponse]);

  if (success) {
    // state of the form wil be reset
  }

  return (
    <form>
      <label htmlFor"username">
      <input type="text" id="username" />
      <button type="submit">Save</button>
    </form>
  )
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The first question to ask yourself about mocking is "do I really need to mock this?" The most straightforward solution here is to test "component" directly instead of trying to fake out an http HOC wrapper around it.

I generally avoid trying to unit test things related to I/O. Those things are best handled with functional or integration tests. You can accomplish that by making sure that, given same props, component always renders the same output. Then, it becomes trivial to unit test component with no mocks required.

Then use functional and/or integration tests to ensure that the actual http I/O happens correctly

To more directly answer you question though, jest.fn is not a component, but React is expecting one. If you want the mock to work, you must give it a real component.

Your sample code here doesn't make sense because every part of your example is fake code. Which real code are you trying to test? I've seen gigantic test files that never actually exercize any real code - they were just testing an elaborate system of mocks. Be careful not to fall into that trap.

Comment: I am mocking a response from an API. This get's passed through to my 
component via props using a react-refetch HOC. I want to test the component against different outcomes of the API (204, 500 etc.).

Comment: Added some of the sample code to give a general idea. Hope that makes more sense.